# OpenCV match template

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to match a logo (template) I have with some images. My images are all colored in nature and the way I am doing it is using the cvMatchTemplate() from openCV and running the template (logo) over my source image. I scale the template to multiple levels to find the best match. Please note that I am just finding the digitally imprinted logos  on the image and not the logos present in the scene. 
Eg: Detecting sky sports from this image http://i56.tinypic.com/2v3j3wx.jpg (The image is purely for representation and clarity of my task and is not images I am working with

My images are not of fixed resolution so I scale it up to a standard 800x600. Now when my source image resolution is very bad say 300x300, the results are very ordinary. I am using the method=CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED in the template parameter and the scores even for accurate matches is quite low (as low as 0.4 on a scale of 0 to 1.0) making it difficult for me to confidently say if the logo is present or not.
I have two questions on this:

1 - In opencv template matching, how does it handle colored images. I tried to comprehend from the document and my inference was it computes the score for each channel separately and the best is taken. If that is the case wont I would be better off taking all the three channels into account for better results

2 - Any alternative approach !! :)

Let me know if any thing is not clear !

EDIT (Additional information):
As discussed in the comments I am attaching my current matching technique which is scaled template matching. Please note the attached images are purely for test purposes and is not my actual set of images I am working with (cannot post as the images are proprieotry) 
Source Image[image: A screen shot from youtube]
Logo Image [image: Got from wikipedia]
Output Image using Template matching [image: Red block indicating the best match wrt highest score]

Although template is matched the score obtained here is 0.59 for this best match. Although relatively its a good score for a match, but still not good enough for me to tell for sure that the desired logo exists or not. In my test images when the logo on screen is transparent, it would still detect the logo but with a poor score of 0.3-0.4. Can a better result be obtained using SURF/SIFT?

EDIT (Attempt with SURF)
I tried to run a SURF code already given as an example in the opencv offical documentation (minHessian = 2000).[link here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)
here is the output. I am not sure how to interpret it (2,3 points seem to be within the expected boundary. Is this considered good? Any further suggestions?
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Normalized cross-correlation is likely a too weak method for the task. You might want a keypoint detector followed by keypoint matching in the two images. One typical method for such thing is called SURF. Can you include the actual images (the bad one, and the template) that you desire to match ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did consider SIFT/SURF techniques but I  was advised by some, it was an overkill for my application. But I want to be sure that SURF would improve my precision. Any heads up as to how to go about the task apart from reading the SURF sample codes.


The images are proprietary in nature, however I would try and replicate the behavior in freely available images and post them here for better clarity to the problem.

Comment: To be sure that SURF improves your precision it is simple: use it and check if it improves your precision. Who advised you against it ? And what was the reason ? (overkill surely isn't a reason).

Comment: As for your first question: how would you combine all the three channels ? There is no globally accepted method for that, but one common thing in that regard is moving to the CIELAB color space and considering euclidean distance there (the simplest Delta E).

Comment: Thank you again. I will definitely try SURF and see if it improves. An acquaintance who has previously worked in the image processing techniques advised me so, the reasoning was since my application was trying to detect logos that are not rotation invariant and remain exactly the same except scale factors, SURF will not give me a better result than template matching. The reasoning may be flawed and since you suggest I will try it out.
Also in case as i suspected only one channel was taken into conseration I was planning to convert to HSI or HSL space and analyze further (just a thought)

Comment: Is it really exact the same ? Isn't the logo semi-transparent so the image you have below it may in fact modify it a lot ? Is it really always perfectly in the same rotation ? Is the image acquisition that good ? Also, you mention scaling, how is that not taking scale into consideration ? These statements you received as suggestion seem wrong in every instance I can imagine.

Comment: Is it really always perfectly in the same rotation? Yes, no change in rotation. Also, you mention scaling, how is that not taking scale into consideration ? I take a standard sized logo and run the template match for 10 different scales of the logo on the same image for the best score. Is it really exact the same ? Yes. Rest of the questions you pose, I dont have answers, making me believe that I should a give a very good try at SURF technique !!

Comment: If you could include any images I would attempt something, and maybe a more relevant comment/answer.

Comment: @mmgp I have attached the current template matching technique. Can there be some improvement using SURF/SIFT?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using a Gaussian Blur on your Source Image before performing template matching? This may give you more accurate results as I think it's the quality of the source image that's giving a worse match

Link to Gaussian Blur in OpenCV Docs :

[OpenCV Python Gaussian Blur](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussian%20blur#cv2.GaussianBlur)

Alternatively you could try a histogram comparison technique on the area template matching suggests, for an extra confirmation that the Template Match correlation returned, even if small, is the correct value :

[Drawing Histograms](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html)

Drawing the histograms is optional, it might be useful for your own application

[Comparing the Histograms](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html?highlight=histogram%20comparison)

^ This method calculates the histograms of your images (source and template) and the correlation between them...
However, you don't want a Histogram of the entire source, just where your Template Matching thinks the best correlation is, or some other location in the image, so you want to get a Histogram of a Region of Interest (ROI) instead, see the following C++ code :

```
Mat OriginalImage = imread("source.jpg", 0);
Rect RegionOfInterest = Rect(150, 150, 250, 250);
Mat ROIImage = OriginalImage(RegionOfInterest);
```

This lets you calculate the histogram of a region of interest. You should get a Histogram of your template and a histogram for the region where Template Matching thinks your template is in the source and compare them to confirm or refute the Template Matching output

Comment: Hi, No I did not do a gaussian blurr,  and u r right the quality is suffering in the image where as my template image is of high quality. So should I do a gaussian blurr on the template logo image ?

Comment: The idea of Gaussian Blur is to remove information - I suggested you add it to the system because I think it would simplify setting template matching (correlation) thresholds - So I would say it depends, I would usually blur the Source, but because the template is of better quality I would play around with this method, mainly trying to blur the template and the Source, or just blurring the template (but because I haven't seen the images a blur of the source could work too, but most likely not as well as the other two solution...)
I've attached a link to Gaussian Blur in the documentation

Comment: BTW, If template matching doesn't work I have another simple Image Processing Technique you could use for detection, but first we will see if Gaussian Blur helps

Comment: it would be great if u could let me know that technique as well. the question has been pending since quite a while, i would try it out and post results in a day !

Comment: Great, let me know how it goes - I'll add the other technique to my answer so it's clearer

Comment: Gaussian Blurring on the template image is defiintely increasing my scoring, from 0.59 to the above image to 0.72. On the downside even for images that dont have the logo, the scoring has increased but by a lesser factor (which is good). I will do some testing and analysis on the method u prescribed and get back with details !! Thanks definitely encouraging results

Comment: Great! That unfortunately is a downfall of Gaussian Blur, in this case it will help you get a more accurate match by removing information that obscures a match - but this is true for all photos and a template under Gaussian Blur will look far similar to other images than a template that wasn't blurred.
Let me know how it goes! Feel free to ask any follow up questions in the mean time as well

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26095/discussion-between-ajay-nair-and-matt-mcgrath)